# Change the column header text for DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Right now, I am trying to create a table with custom code for my Java application (Swing GUI). I create the table with this code:

```
DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(9,5);
```

I got 5 columns with 9 rows for the table: I just want to rename/change the header text for the columns, because right now they have name like A,B,C,D and so on!

Comment: Try actually RTFM for the API being used. The clue is in the [constructors for `DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#constructor.summary). As a general tip, don't come running to SO with every question that arises in programming. **Consult the documentation first.**

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I found a solution!

Comment: *"I found a solution!"* Glad you got it solved! :) Now yo might answer your own question below (not as a comment). Or.. simply delete it using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I used DefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount) to solve my problem!